# Display ImageField in UpdateView Django

Tags: javascript, html, css, django, django-templates

- I have an image field in profile model.
- I am not able to save the image from template.
- Tried saving image using django admin, it successfully saves the
  image but I couldn't display the image in the update view.

My question is how do I save and display the image using the same template and the same form in django.

**Model**

```
class Profile(models.Model):
    image         = models.ImageField(upload_to='profile_images', null=True, blank=True)
    profile_email = models.CharField(max_length=30, null=True, blank=True)
    biography     = models.CharField(max_length=700, null=True, blank=True)
```

**View**

```
class ProfileSettingsView(UpdateView):
    model = Profile
    form_class = ProfileSettingsForm
    pk_url_kwarg = 'pk'
    context_object_name = 'object'
    template_name = 'profile_settings.html'

    def get_success_url(self):
          return reverse_lazy('users:profile_settings', args = (self.object.id,))
```

**Template**

```
<form style="padding-left: 15px; padding-right:15px;" method="POST" enctype='multipart/form-data'>
    {{ form.errors }}
    {% csrf_token %}
    <h7>Note: Everything added in this section will be public.</h7>
    <hr>
    <br>
    <h3>Profile picture</h3>
    <hr>
    <div style="text-align:center;" class="row">
        <div style="text-align:center;" class="col-lg-12">
            <div class="container_image">
                <div class="avatar-upload-image">
                    <div class="avatar-edit-image">
                        <input type='file' id="imageUpload" name="image" accept=".png, .jpg, .jpeg"  />
                        <label for="imageUpload"></label>
                    </div>
                    <div class="avatar-preview">
                        <div id="imagePreview">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>


    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-6">
            <div class="form-group">
                <div class="field">
                    <label>Full Name<span class="red-txt">*</span></label>
                    <!-- <input class="form-control" type="text" name="full_name" value="{{ full_name }}" maxlength="60" size="50"> -->
                    {{ form.full_name }}
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-6">
            <div class="form-group">
                <div class="field">
                    <label>Email<span class="red-txt">*</span></label>
                    {{ form.profile_email }}
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
</form>
```

**JS**

```
    function read_profile_image_url(input) {
    if (input.files && input.files[0]) {
        var reader = new FileReader();
        reader.onload = function(e) {
            $('#imagePreview').css('background-image', 'url('+e.target.result +')');
            $('#imagePreview').hide();
            $('#imagePreview').fadeIn(650);
        }
        reader.readAsDataURL(input.files[0]);
    }
}

$("#imageUpload").change(function() {
            read_profile_image_url(this);
        });
```

Comment: `{{ form.instance.image.url }}` is the url of the existing image, you need pass that somewhere in your template to use as the source url. Now there's nothing in your HTML that references your image. Note your probably need to prefix with the `MEDIA_URL`